# Android Custom Component not being displayed

Tags: android, components

Having a problem with Android Custom components. Trying to draw an oval shape but nothing happening.

I have this line in layout xml file

```
        <android.project.realtimedata.DemoView android:id="@+id/demoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Here is the code for my custom component class.

```
    package android.project.realtimedata;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.drawable.ShapeDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.shapes.OvalShape;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class DemoView extends View{
     ShapeDrawable thisGauge = null;    
     public DemoView(Context context){
            super(context);
            init();
        }
        public DemoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
        {
            super(context, attrs);
            init();
        }
        private void init(){
            int x = 10;
            int y = 10;
            int width = 300;
            int height = 50;

            thisGauge = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
            thisGauge.getPaint().setColor(0xff74AC23);
            thisGauge.setBounds(x, y, x + width, y + height);
        }

        @Override 
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            thisGauge.draw(canvas); 
        }
    }
```

I also have this line in onCreate method of Activity

```
demoView = (DemoView) findViewById(R.id.demoView);
```

Whenever I launch the application the custom component is not there.
I tried looking at it from LogCat and it definitely gets created.
What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What content are you "wrapping"? Is it possible, if you have no objects/text inside the custom view, that it is simply wrapping a content of zero height, resulting in an oval of zero height?
Try setting the xml layout_height as fill_parent and see if that changes anything?

Comment: may I post this as an answer and humbly request that you accept it? :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you calling `findViewById(R.id.demoView)` **after** calling `setContentView(...)`. To ensure that your view is being inflated, you can call `Log.d("DemoView", "Created")` from inside your `DemoView` constructor.